# How do I output a DateTime field as milliseconds in my view?

Tags: django, python-3.x, datetime, view, milliseconds

I'm using Python 3.7 and Django.  I have this field in my model ...

```
class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

Then in my view, I'm trying to output this field in a data attribute as milliseconds, so I tried

```
 data-created-on="{{  article.created_on.timestamp() * 1000 }}"
```

However, this is resulting in the error when my view is rendered ...

```
Could not parse the remainder: '() * 1000' from 'article.created_on.timestamp() * 1000'
```

What's the proper way to output my DateTime field as a time in milliseconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a property method to your model to return the time in milliseconds:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    @property
    def created_on_ms(self):
        return self.created_on.timestamp() * 1000
```

Then in your view you would use the `created_on_ms` property.

```
data-created-on="{{  article.created_on_ms }}"
```